# Drop Down Menu Issue on Joomla Website in IE explorer

Tags: php, css, joomla, superfish

I have my client whose side panel shows correctly on Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't show well on IE.

I have even tried using 
                    `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` and 
              `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,9,10" />` but somehow using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,9,10" >` the drop down menu is overlapping the page content.

http://www.cleanenergycentre.com.au/index.php/solarpower/solar-panels

Comment: It looks the same on IE and Firefox to me...

Comment: Sorry but look at the solar power side menu panel having Solar Power Products

    Solar Panels
        Munchen Solar EnergieRenesolaSharp SolarQ-CellsTrina SolarSolar Inverters
        SMA InvertersPower One / AuroraSolis InvertersDelta Inverters

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the z-index simply add position:relative to the container

```
DIV#dropdownmenuContainer{
position:relative;
}
```

and to your template.css add this part of code to fix the width of the li's width into the dropdown

```
DIV#dropdownmenuContainer ul li li{
*display:block;
}
```

Comment: Hello user1055160 i didn't get the 2nd part of your answer

Comment: The second part worked for me in ie7 to fix the width of the dropdown's li's